# Switch-based URL routing in PHP

Tags: php, url-routing

What I'm currently doing is this:

I have a `$path` variable, which is everything after *index.php/* (which I hide with .htaccess) up to a question mark to ignore the querystring.

Then I use a `switch` with `preg_match` cases on that variable to determine what script it should call. For example:

```
switch (true)
{  
  case preg_match('{products/view/(?P<id>\d+)/?}', $path, $params): 
    require 'view_product.php'; 
  break;

  ...  

  default:
    require '404.php';
  break;
}
```

This way I can access the product id just using `$params['id']` and, if needed, use the querystring for filtering, pagination, etc.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn’t use `switch` like this.

Better use an array and `foreach` like:

```
$rules = array(
    '{products/view/(?P<id>\d+)/?}' => 'view_product.php'
);
$found = false;
foreach ($rules as $pattern => $target) {
    if (preg_match($pattenr, $path, $params)) {
        require $target;
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$found) {
    require '404.php';
}
```

Comment: Whoa. That simple, huh? Thanks, dude. Seems way better than my approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

The wrong part would be the switch case .  As a better practice i would suggest you store all regex into an array and test it with that . It would be easyer to save the routes to a config file , or an ini file or database or xml or whatever will make you're life easyer in to long run ( if you need to edit/add/delete new routes ) .

In the second part you could use parse_url php function instead of regex witch will speed you're script a bit .