# configuring url routes php with wildcard, checking for GET_ data

Tags: php, routes

I'm trying to understand what is going wrong here. I'm using php's routes through a switch.

`localhost/bonify` redirects to the correct place.

`localhost/bonify?datasetID=1a2b3c4d5e6f7`  redirects to the 404.

`http://localhost/bonify/split` goes to the correct place.

`localhost/bonify/split?datasetID=1a2b3c4d5e6f7`  redirects to the 404.

So how do I allow `localhost/bonify?datasetID=1a2b3c4d5e6f7` to pass through to the `bonify.php`? I'm guessing some kind of pattern match [0-9],['a'-'z'] through `preg_match`? Or some kind of wildcard, but allowing `localhost/bonify/split` not to be confused with `localhost/bonify`.

Perhaps the `?` should be part of the pattern match? I hope that makes sense?

```
 $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

 switch ($request) {
     case '/' :
         require __DIR__ . '\bonify'. $version . '\home.php';
         break;
     case '' :
         require __DIR__ . '\bonify'. $version . '\app\bonify.php';
         break;
     case '/bonify' :
         require __DIR__ . '\bonify'. $version . '\app\bonify.php';
         break;

     case '/bonify/split' :
         require __DIR__ . '\bonify'. $version . '\app\bonify_split.php';
         break;
```

Answer (score 1):

The switch statement looks for a string identical to the pattern. The easiest way to find out why your statement does not work is to print the `$request` variable out and compare it with your cases.

For `localhost/bonify`:

```
$request = /bonify
```

And it matches the pattern.

For `localhost/bonify?datasetID=1a2b3c4d5e6f7`:

```
$request = /bonify?datasetID=1a2b3c4d5e6f7
```

**"/bonify?datasetID=1a2b3c4d5e6f7" !== "/bonify"**

That does not match any pattern. You don't have a default case in your switch statement so you get 404.

The only way I see is to use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function in your cases (with a correct regex) to cover all possible options.

Edit: If you don't need the ID from the URL in that part of the code, you can just cut all characters from the question mark (`substr()` method) and save the result to the new variable. Then just use the new variable in your switch statement. It would also work.

```
 $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $cutRequest = strpos($request, "?") ? explode("?", $request)[0] : $request;
 switch ($cutRequest) {
 // ....
 }
```

Comment: I'd like to continue to use the `GET_` function as I'll be passing variables through the url. Surely there's a way to say `/bonify` and/or to ignore and [0-9],[a-z] string that follows the `?` while still passing it to the web page?

Comment: @SpatialDigger I added an example

Comment: I'm thinking it might be better to use something similar to this example rather than case/break? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595624/switch-based-url-routing-in-php

Comment: I mentioned that before edition :) "The only way I see is to use preg_match() function in your cases (with a correct regex) to cover all possible options."